# How to append text.concordance to a variable list?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I am using the NLTK toolkit, and I am using the `text.concordance()` function. I would like to append the results of this function to a `list`, in order to get a `list` of the string-sentences the function outputs.

[image: Example Output of Concordance]

I have tried to define the function as a variable and tried to append this to the variable list.

I have tried to define the variable as the function itself:

```
sim_col_inst = text.concordance("column")

type(sim_col_inst)
NoneType
```

Alternatively, I have tried to append this:

```
sim_col_inst.append(text.concordance("column"))

type(sim_col_inst)
list
```

However, the variables are always empty.

Answer (score 2):

The `concordance` method of `nltk.text.Text` only *prints* the concordance, and then returns `None`.

You can use the method `concordance_list` instead to get a list.